# How to improve speed when uploading large files using OneDrive SDK

Tags: c#, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

When uploading large file attachments using OneDrive SDK, the speed is too slow.

It takes about 45 minutes to 1 hour based on 1GB file.

Is there any way to improve the problem?

```
public async Task<JObject> UploadLargeFiles(string upn, IFormFile files)
    {
        var jObject = new JObject();
        int fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(files.Length);
        var fileStream = files.OpenReadStream();

        GraphServiceClient client = await MicrosoftGraphClient.GetGraphServiceClient();

        var uploadProps = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
        {
            ODataType = null,
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename" }
            }
        };

        var item = this.SelectUploadFolderID(upn).Result;
        var uploadSession = await client.Users[upn].Drive.Items[item].ItemWithPath(files.FileName).CreateUploadSession(uploadProps).Request().PostAsync();

        int maxChunkSize = 320 * 1024;
        var uploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, fileStream, maxChunkSize);

        var response = await uploadTask.UploadAsync();

        if (response.UploadSucceeded)
        {
            jObject = JObject.FromObject(new { result = "success"});
            return jObject;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have followed the examples/guidance's provided at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/uploading-large-files-using-microsoft-graph-api/ba-p/510041 and it worked for me. I know uploading bigger files may take a while, give a fact that it depends on the internet speed, so i will exclude Graph API out of the picture here. Apart from that i dont see any options to speedup.

Comment: If you think you this needs to be considered by Microsoft, then file a Microsoft Uservoice - so that they can have a look at it. Here's the related uservoice item that i can think - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37254625-enable-parallel-out-of-sequence-large-file-uploads. Consider upvoting it or create a new file...!! Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Moving this to answer - as it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the examples/guidance's provided at [blogpost](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/uploading-large-files-using-microsoft-graph-api/ba-p/510041) and it worked for me. I know uploading bigger files may take a while, give a fact that it depends on the internet speed, so i will exclude Graph API out of the picture here. Apart from that i dont see any options to speedup. Also you can consider filing [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37254625-enable-parallel-out-of-sequence-large-file-uploads).

Comment: I did it right in angular without requesting it with rest API. The speed has improved a lot. The link below that you posted was helpful.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/uploading-large-files-using-microsoft-graph-api/ba-p/510041

Comment: Glad to hear, the link helped you moving forward :)